# Can a creature attack another creature's shield or weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat

Can a creature (a PC or an NPC) attack another creature's shield or weapon?

Comment: I’ve undelete this because we like duplicates — they provide valuable signposts toward the existing answers, improving the site’s usefulness to future searchers like yourself. Thank you for the contribution!